# Can I interrupt a task in inkscape?

Tags: linux, inkscape

I have launched a "tiled clones" task in inkscape. Rather than setting a number of clones, I have selected an area to cover. Inkscape has been working at it at 100% CPU for 1/2 an hour now...

I'd like to interrupt this task. However there seems to be nothing on the interface, and escape key was not heeded either. There are unsaved details in the drawing.

Any idea?